# Comparison between pseudoinverse and perturbed matrix

Tags: singularity, matrix-analysis

Let $A$ be a singular matrix. I would like to understand the behavior of $A^{+}$ compared to $(A+\epsilon I)^{-1}$.

The reason I'm asking is because I want to understand $MB^{+}M^{*}$ if $M=(AB)^{1/2}$.

If $B$ were nonsingular, then
$$
MB^{-1}M^{*} = (AB)^{1/2}B^{-1}(BA)^{1/2}=B^{-1}B(AB)^{1/2}B^{-1}(BA)^{1/2}
= B^{-1}(BA)^{1/2}(BA)^{1/2}=B^{-1}BA=A.
$$

I'd like to show, for the same choice of $M$, that $MB^{+}M^{*} \leq A$ when $B$ is singular. This is clearly the case if it's nonsingular, but not sure how to proceed otherwise.

Now I have
$$
MB^{+}M^{*} = (AB)^{1/2}B^{+}(BA)^{1/2}
$$
and is there any way to make sense of this compared to $M(B+\epsilon I)^{-1}M^{*}$ using a continuity argument?

Comment: Given that $A^{+}(A + \epsilon I) = A^{+} A + \epsilon A^{+}$, exactly what information about that expression are you hoping to get?

Comment: Oh oops that third sentence isn't quite right -- it's the last line that's important.

Comment: I cannot comment on the inequality that you want to show, but a continuity argument seems like it wouldn't work because the inverse is unstable. In the direction of the null space of $B$ the singular values of $(B + \epsilon I)^{-1}$ would scale like $1/\epsilon$.

Comment: Why is that true? Don’t see why that’s immediately obvious.

Comment: If $B = U \Sigma V^{\ast}$, then writing $I = UU^{\ast} VV^{\ast}$ you can write $B + \epsilon I = U (\Sigma + \epsilon U^{\ast} V) V^{\ast}$. For $\epsilon$ small, $\Sigma + \epsilon U^{\ast} V$ is nearly diagonal, so the new singular values will look like $\sigma_i + \alpha_i \epsilon $, where $\sigma_i$ were the singular values of $B$ and $\alpha_i$ are constants that depend on the angle between $U$ and $V$ vectors. When you take pseudoinverse you normally "zero out" the null space portion but now you don't have a null space, instead you have a large singular value in that direction.